# Making entire form readonly in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

Is this possible to make the whole form readonly with only one (or two) lines of code, as it is in PEAR/QuickForm?

I have the following code:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user) 
                ->add('username', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType::class, array('label' => 'Login: '))
                ->add('personal_name', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType::class, array('label' => 'Imię i nazwisko: '))
(...)
```

I know I can add `"read_only" => true` to every "add" function call, but is there a one-liner?

I also tried to use an AbstractType like this:

```
class Register extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
            'readonly' => true //I also tried read_only, read-only, read only but to no avail  
        ));
    }
```

The above code doesn't work, although when I replaced `'readonly' => true` with `'disabled' => true` it... worked. However I want it to be readonly.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is that I want to have ONE view (twig template, a form) for adding new entity, edit existing entity and displaying entity's details (this is where readonly would be useful). Maybe you have a better idea?

I know I can do this with Javascript, but maybe there is a Symfony - way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"read_only" was deprecated in Symfony 2.8, in favour of passing read only as an attribute instead. Try the following:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'validation_groups' => ['registration'],
        'attr' => ['readonly' => true],  
    ]);
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! Do you know where it is documented?

Comment: Changelog: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/CHANGELOG.md#280 Instigator: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10533 Change: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10658

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I couldn't find it.